# How would I wrap (or hard-code) HTML into a block title?

Tags: blocks, theming

So I see this in the `block.tpl.php`:

```
/**
* @file
* Default theme implementation to display a block.
*
* Available variables:
* - $block->subject: Block title.
* - $content: Block content.
* - $block->module: Module that generated the block.
* - $block->delta: An ID for the block, unique within each module.
* - $block->region: The block region embedding the current block.
* - $classes: String of classes that can be used to style contextually through
*   CSS. It can be manipulated through the variable $classes_array from
*   preprocess functions. The default values can be one or more of the
*   following:
*   - block: The current template type, i.e., "theming hook".
*   - block-[module]: The module generating the block. For example, the user
*     module is responsible for handling the default user navigation block. In
*     that case the class would be 'block-user'.
* - $title_prefix (array): An array containing additional output populated by
*   modules, intended to be displayed in front of the main title tag that
*   appears in the template.
* - $title_suffix (array): An array containing additional output populated by
*   modules, intended to be displayed after the main title tag that appears in
*   the template.
*
```

I'm trying to set the `$title_prefix` & `$title_suffix` in my `hook_block_view` without much luck...

Here is the working version of what I have:

```
/**
* Implements hook_block_view().
*/
function activities_block_view($delta = '') {
 switch ($delta) {
   case 'find_activities_small':
     $block['subject'] = t('Find Activities');
     $block['content'] = drupal_get_form('find_activities_form');
     return $block;
     break;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Core (modules/block/block.tpl.php) and other themes I checked output the title_prefix with:

```
<?php print render($title_prefix); ?>
```

Therefore, the format of $title_prefix is any renderable array. You can override theme_preprocess_block() function in template.php to supply values. For example,

```
function mytheme_preprocess_block(&$variables) {
  $variables['title_prefix'] = array(
    '#type' => 'markup',
    '#markup' => '<span>My title prefix</span>',
  );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

1. You can hard code in block template: ["Drupal 7 Template Suggestions"](http://drupal.org/node/1089656), so determine what module/delta/region appropriate for you.
2. Other way is using theme [preprocessor](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.module/function/template_preprocess_block/7).

Answer (score 0):

Why insert more html when you can simply use css with a class insert through the [Block Class](https://www.drupal.org/project/block_class) module? Here is an excerpt about it from the module's project page:

> ... allows users to add classes to any block through the block's configuration interface. By adding a very short snippet of PHP to a theme's block.tpl.php file, classes can be added to the parent `<div class="block ...">` element of a block. Hooray for more powerful block theming!

Comment: Adding wrapper is different from adding a class... and even adding class with block_class will add a class to the block itself not to the block-title